# Getting error in xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

My xsl file like below:

```
 <SELECT>
  <xsl:attribute name="name">Team</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="size">1</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="onchange">selTeam_onclick()</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:if test='.[z:row]'>
    <xsl:for-each select="z:row">
      <OPTION>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
          <xsl:value-of select="@TEAM_ID"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if match='.[@TEAM_ID=@DEFAULTID]'>
          <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@TEAM_NAME"/>
      </OPTION>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test='.[$not$ z:row]'>
    <OPTION>
      <xsl:attribute name="value">-1</xsl:attribute>
      No Teams
    </OPTION>
  </xsl:if>
</SELECT>
```

For the xml file

```
<z:row TEAM_ID="1" TEAM_NAME="John" TEAM_LIST_TYPE="PUBLIC" TEAM_EDITABLE="Y" TEAM_OWNER="234"/>
<z:row TEAM_ID="2" TEAM_NAME="Maria" TEAM_LIST_TYPE="PUBLIC" TEAM_EDITABLE="Y" TEAM_OWNER="545"/>
<z:row TEAM_ID="3" TEAM_NAME="Dick" TEAM_LIST_TYPE="PUBLIC" TEAM_EDITABLE="N" TEAM_OWNER="766"/>
```

When i am trying to generate the html through the above xsl file, getting error of xpath expression.

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to bind the dropdown through html and that html using xml and xsl file.

Comment: Please show minimal but complete snippets of XML and XSLT to allow us to reproduce the problem, together with information on the XSLT processor used. Are you sure you are at all trying to use XSLT 1.0 as standardized by the W3C? `.[$not$ z:row]` is certainly not XSLT/XPath 1.0. Have you taken that code from an example of a different language?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl" version="1.0" language="JavaScript">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rs:data">                                                                                       Please help me its urgent.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider to post your code snippets in the question, not in comments. As for your code, the XSLT language was standardized in 1999 as version 1.0 by the W3C and uses the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`. You seem to be trying to use a predecessor only supported by old Microsoft MSXML versions. I don't remember details of the syntax and semantics differences and I think Microsoft does not even have a documentation on it online so I can't help with that.

Comment: xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document) returns null

Comment: Note also that the input shown is not well-formed XML (unbound prefix and no single root element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the XSLT snippet you have shown, the correct code to use is as follows:

```
    <SELECT>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">Team</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="size">1</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="onchange">selTeam_onclick()</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:if test='z:row'>
        <xsl:for-each select="z:row">
          <OPTION>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
              <xsl:value-of select="@TEAM_ID"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test='@TEAM_ID=@DEFAULTID'>
              <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="@TEAM_NAME"/>
          </OPTION>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test='not(z:row)'>
        <OPTION>
          <xsl:attribute name="value">-1</xsl:attribute>
          No Teams
        </OPTION>
      </xsl:if>
    </SELECT>
```

The two main changes were

- Replace `<xsl:if match=...` with `<xsl:if test=...`
- Replace `$not$` with the `not()` function

As mentioned already, you will also need to change the namespace declaration to `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`, and also remove the "language" attribute. For example (update the namespace URIs to match your actual ones)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
    xmlns:rs="rs" 
    xmlns:z="z" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="rs z">
```

See this in action at http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSz

The fact your comments show you had `language="JavaScript"` on the xsl:stylesheet element suggests that perhaps your actual XSLT is also using `<xsl:script>` or maybe `<xsl:eval>`, which I vaguely remember were supported. If so, your refactoring of the XSLT will be a bigger task.

Should you need to ask another question about other parts of your XSLT, do follow the advice Michael Kay has given you in his answer.

Comment: Can you please help me for the below scripst of xslt  **<xsl:if test='z:row[index() $gt$ 5]'>** and **<xsl:if test='.[$not$ z:row]'>**  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Saying "please help me it's urgent" tends to discourage people from responding, because they think you're in panic mode and aren't going to read and apply the answer carefully enough.
2. Telling us you get an error, without telling us what the error is, is distinctly unfriendly. Do you expect us to help you when blindfolded?
3. As Martin points out, your supplementary information shows that you are using the old Microsoft WD-xsl language which was introduced in IE4 in 1998, a few months before XSLT 1.0 was finalized. This language has been obsolete for almost 20 years and only works in very restricted environments; furthermore, Microsoft have managed to remove all trace of it from the web so it's very hard to find a spec.
4. The only sensible advice I can give you is to move forward from WD-xsl to some version of XSLT, preferably a modern version. Sadly, because you're in panic mode with a deadline approaching, I fear that advice isn't going to be welcome.